# Getting the deleted record from a bindingNavigator

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingsource, bindingnavigator

Using C# Winforms, I have a form with a BindingNavigator.
When the user clicks the delete button I want to log the record before it is deleted.

It is easy to tell that delete has been clicked using

```
private void bindingSource_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemDeleted)
 {
 }
}
```

However BindingSource.ListChanged is a completed event which fires after the row
deletion is done. When this event is firing, the row is already deleted so how can I trap it?

I am binding to a list of objects.

```
    this.bindingSource.DataSource = Controller.Data;  // returning a List<Person>()
    this.bindingNavigator.BindingSource = this.bindingSource;
```

.

Comment: Are you binding to a `DataTable`? If so, you can directly handle the `RowDeleting` event.

Answer (score 1):

The bindingNavigator has a ToolStripItem called bindingNavigatorDeleteItem 
The bindingNavigator's DeleteItem property had been set to this ToolStripItem.
Instead I set it to none.
Then set the Click Event of the bindingNavigatorDeleteItem  ToolStripItem

```
this.bindingNavigatorDeleteItem.Click += this.bindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click;

private void bindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.bindingSource.EndEdit();
        MyLogger( this.bindingSource.Current);
        this.bindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
    }
```